# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException in Android Developers consolee

Tags: android, eclipse

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{appinventor.ai_kksal55.Fikralar10000/appinventor.ai_kksal55.Fikralar10000.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: android_metadata
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: android_metadata
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:2015)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1872)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:822)
at appinventor.ai_kksal55.Fikralar10000.DatabaseHelper.openDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:141)
at appinventor.ai_kksal55.Fikralar10000.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

my MainActivity.java

```
 kategoriler = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);      
    try { myDbHelper.createDataBase();}
    catch (IOException ioe) {throw new Error("Unable to create database");}


    try { myDbHelper.openDataBase();}
    catch(SQLException sqle){   throw sqle; }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VeriTabanı Başarıyla Güncellendi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and DatabaseHelper.java

```
package appinventor.ai_kksal55.Fikralar10000;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.R.array;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{ 
    String DB_PATH =null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "anddb3";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {"_id", "adi"};
    private final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH="/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+"databases/";
    }   
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
    }else{

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }
}
private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}
@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
 //return cursor
    public Cursor query(String table,String[] columns, String selection,String[] selectionArgs,String groupBy,String having,String orderBy){
        return myDataBase.query("kat", null, null, null, null, null, null);

    }

    }
```

database is 17 MB.

Why do you lock applications. The application did not work 
user's phone "Android 2.3.3 - 2.3.7 Galaxy Y (GT-S5360)"

me and my friend, my application works fine. In some people sometimes will not turn on

Comment: post your database code

Comment: post the database creation code so that we can see whether something is missing or not.

Comment: Give upvote to my answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Major Problem it is showing like there is no such table found android_metadata**

**Check the directories are correctly placed. because you are importing database from your device i think.**

> And are you sure you have created the Database correctly?

again problem. place your Database code.